# Star Rating Control for iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiview

In my application i have to implement star rating control, in which i have to maintain float value means fullselectedImage, halfselectedimage also.

I have seen this  http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view link

but i was unable to modify the code for half selected image.

Can any body help me out how to do this control.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rating

Comment: @MidhunMP,  I have seen those controls but i didn't get any control for proper float value,some are old one which are not useful for iOS8

Comment: check [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rateview), [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/axratingview)

Comment: @FahimParkar, It depends on slider value , but i want selected event values for stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify "handleTouchAtLocation" as follows it will work.

```
  (void)handleTouchAtLocation:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
        if (!self.editable) return;

        float newRating = 0;
        for(int i = self.imageViews.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            UIImageView *imageView = [self.imageViews objectAtIndex:i];
            CGFloat currentLocationX = touchLocation.x;
            if (currentLocationX > imageView.frame.origin.x) {
                if (touchLocation.x > imageView.frame.origin.x +imageView.frame.size.width) {
                    newRating = i+1;
                }
                else{
                    newRating = i+0.5;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        self.rating = newRating;
    }
```

Comment: I have used above code,its incrementing value by 1 means initial i i have given  as   self.rateView.rating = 2.5; But if i clik on star, it should increment by 0.5, i mean step intervals are [0, 0.5,1, 1.5,2,...., 4.5,5]. Do i need to add anything more.

Comment: Ok., Swipe to rate is working fine, right. And the problem is on tap you want 0.5 increment.If so you can add check @ 0.5 incrementing, if self.rating = newRating, add one more 0.5.

Comment: I didn't get you, can you modify above code where to exactly modify

Comment: hey i modified conditions finally got it thanks..